# Early 1900's Paper Puzzle - Release the Key and Live Forever

Tags: real, paper-folding

This puzzle was found in an old attic and was a religious invitation.  Release the key and you could send it in to receive a Bible based book.  Apparently 1000's were made but I can find no more other information about it, nor can I find the solution.  Here's what I do know.

The 3 parts are made from completely different colors of paper so it could not have been manufactured from a single piece.  This means that someone had to assemble it and it should be able to be undone.  While the corners are worn, I inspected them closely and they have not been torn or cut. How can the key be removed? (Click for larger images)

[image: front of puzzle - car with a slit parallel to the bottom, through which is threaded a red locking string with two large leafs on either end, which serve to block a key threaded onto the lock from moving off] [image: back of puzzle]

Comment: The patent number on there refers to a U.S. patent. The specification, which is available online, describes both how the puzzle was manufactured and how to solve it.

Comment: @msh210 that would make a good answer since OP asks about if anyone has seen it before. https://patents.google.com/patent/US695059

Comment: Not the intended answer but I'm thinking take two of these, cut the brown paper of one and keep the freed key and red tag, then cut the tag of the second and keep the in-tact brown paper.

Comment: This looks like it was released by the "International Bible Students Association" of Brooklyn. Today they are known as the Jehovah's Witnesses.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It could be done with some slight folding of the paper, be careful though.

> 1) Carefully pull the bottom corners of the paper together. 
>  
>  2) Make sure that the bottom part of the paper, the strip under
>  the hole, bends outwards away from the rest of the paper.
>  
>  3) Carefully pull the red paperdrop towards you, pulling the
>  paperstrip through the hole of the keyhandle.
>  
>  4) Deattach the paperdrop through the hole the strip formed after it was
>  pulled through the handle.
>
>  5) Take the now free key and go claim your bible!

Comment: alternatively `ebyy gur qebc vagb n plyvaqre`

Comment: I would like to see a video of this solution because I still can't picture it

Comment: @nathanchere; I've posted a picture which might help you see Bjorn's solution.

Answer (score 9):

A picture to illustrate Bjorn's solution:

> [image: bible key]
>
>  The paper from the main leaflet is pulled through the hole in the key to allow one of the red discs through the loop created and release the seal and therefore the key..

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to the puzzle:

[image]

Comment: This is the same as the previous two answers; please do not duplicate answers unless you have something of value to add

Comment: I realise this may be the same approach as one given already in text form, but I do think this illustrated step-by-step style of relaying it makes it much clearer to see and therefore adds value. I certainly followed this answer more easily than I have followed either of the other answers already given.

Comment: @stiv what about the previous answer which has pictures as well?

Comment: @bobble Not step by step enough for me. This answer reads like a helpful set of instructions.